# Spring Integration Aggregation Error

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I have an spring integration implemetation where I have two Client subscribers listening to the same JMS Topic. I am using JDBC message store( Different REGIONS)  in both the implementation to save the incoming messages. While processing the data I get the exception:

```
  org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
```

I know this is Jira issue : https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2912

As now I cant upgrade the Spring version. I am unable to understand the workaround "The work-around is either to always use a different groupKey or to use separate tables for each Message Store. We will need to add a REGION column to the INT_GROUP_TO_MESSAGE as well."

How can i create a different groupKey?

My implementation is as below:

```
<bean
  id="jdbcMessageStore"
  class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageStore"
  p:dataSource-ref="datasource"
  p:region="REPORTS"/>  

<si:aggregator 
        send-partial-result-on-expiry="false" 
        message-store="jdbcMessageStore" 
        discard-channel="discardedLogger"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "groupKey" mentioned there is the correlation strategy result; by default it just uses the correlationId header.

You can use `correlation-strategy-expression="'foo' + headers['correlationId']"` and `correlation-strategy-expression="'bar' + headers['correlationId']"` to use a different group key for each app.